# How can I trim a UIImageView to fit an aspect ratio image

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

I am using a crop tool in my app and I need to modify a UIImageView so that it fits an image exactly after inserting the image in aspect fit mode.

So an image is selected and added to the UIImageView in aspect fit mode. The problem is that this then leaves "blank space" around the image inside the UIImageView that needs trimming. I was wondering how I could then go and resize the holding UIImageView based upon the image inside.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that a better approach is to use the following idea.

[How to get the size of a scaled UIImage in UIImageView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389342/how-to-get-the-size-of-a-scaled-uiimage-in-uiimageview)

Instead of trimming the UIImageView, insert the image and then get the dimensions of the image inside the UIImageView, from there you can then resize the UIImageView to match the dimensions of the image inside.

Answer (score 2):

The Easy way is simply using the following code on your "imageView"

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Assuming you want to cut a "zoomed" section of your image to fit fully into your imageView

1. check your original image width and height
2. Assuming width is bigger in size then height , scale the image width to the holder width
3. center the image on your holder , the width will fit perfectly (section2) and the height will simply be cropped follow above and below the holder.